# HTML not clickable on iPhone Safari

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I am working on a web application using Bootstrap, jQuery and jQuery UI.

My website is working perfectly on all browsers on Windows & Mac OS X expect for Safari browser on iPhone the hole page is not clickable at all including the bootstrap burger menu , I tried many things related to `z-index` but it doesn't worked!

My web app link : http://manage.mylinguisticsolutions.com

please try to open it on iPhone on safari browser

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: my code is on the link

Comment: So you expect people to help you out by viewing source? Instead of sharing your code an pin pointing where the problem is ?

Comment: Try adding  pointer-events: none; to that loaderBody div and see if it resolves. If it does, then your loader overlay is causing you the problem on iOS. Make sure that you are setting it to display:none and not just changing the opacity on it when you remove it from view.

Comment: @KobyDouek There is no script or logic behind the scene, just HTML and CSS if you are welling to help just inspect it , I can't copy all the files here I don't know which file or part causing the problem

Comment: @Korgrue Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't worked, the loaderBody already have `display:none` not `opacity:0`